# How to get Office 365 SharePoint Online permissions in azure management portal?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I am unable to see "Office 365 SharePoint Online" in the list of applications in Permissions section of azure management portal.

[image]

When I try to add the application from gallery, I am unable to add the application to my azure active directory as the "Complete" option is not available.

[image]

Any help in adding the permissions to azure active directory applications would be of great help for me.

Comment: You seem to lack a subscription including SharePoint Online (given the message in the dialogue above)

Comment: @RobertLindgren, what does it meant by "lack a subscription including SharePoint Online"? Is it that, the user id with which I logged into azure management portal should have an office 365 account and SharePoint online subscription?

Comment: Yes exactly, that what I mean